# How to configure and call non-anonymous WCF services from SharePoint application and WPF?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, wcf, iis, sharepoint

We have a CRM/ERP web application (ASP.Net Forms) running on top of SharePoint (WSS and 201x).
On the other hand we have add-ins for Office (WPF) closely integrated to the web application via WCF services.

Both rely heavily on a WCF services project, in three ways:

1. WCF services called from code behind
2. AJAX-enabled client web services using webhttpbinding / enablewebscript
3. WCF services called from the add-ins.

However, there is a security concern. 
In our current set-up, the WCF services need to be set to  Anonymous authentication.
Otherwise our web application and add-ins won't work using the current configuration.

**Our goal**: to disable the anonymous access to the WCF services somehow, without breaking either the web application or add-ins.

This proved much less straight-forward than expected.

**This is our typical set-up**:

- Extended SharePoint site (WSS / 201x). Alternate Access Mapping
  configuration:

  - Default: Active Directory, NTLM.
  - Intranet: Membership Provider, Anonymous access.
- ASP.Net web application runs within the main SharePoint web application (no sub web application in IIS).
- WCF services project is configured in IIS as a 'sub' web application beneath the SharePoint web application.

**This is what we came up with so far**:

- Added  in the WCF services web.config
- Changed **Windows Authentication -> Advanced Settings** to the following:

  - Extended Protection: **Accept**
  - [X] **Enable** Kernel-mode authentication
- Changed client binding configuration of add-ins and web application to Security Mode **TransportCredentialOnly** with clientCredentialType **Ntlm**.

Above solution works in our SharePoint 2007 test environment in all three aforementioned places.

However in SharePoint 201x we can't get the WCF calls from within the web application to work.
At least not using the same client bindings as the add-ins (while the WCF calls from the add-ins also work in SharePoint 2013).

The error message we’re getting is: **No credentials are available in the security package**.
Another one we encountered is: **Provider type not defined**. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090017)

**Question**: How can we use WCF services non-anonymously from within a SharePoint web application and from WPF?

Any idea's on how to configure and call these in this scenario? (one way or another)

Any thoughts on this are greatly appreciated!

Comment: **Update**: we've looked into securing WCF services via ADFS, which looked promising at first. But unfortunately, this is not a viable option, because it involves a lot of configuration on the Domain Controller, and that is not something we can do easily in the environments of our customers.

Comment: Our best lead at the moment is an article on WCF services with claims-based authentication and authorization:

https://www.future-processing.pl/blog/wcf_services_with_claims-based_authentication_and_authorization/

Of course we wouldn't want to use our own custom STS, but use the SecurityTokenService of SharePoint to do this.

Comment: But of course many roads lead to Rome...Are there about other ways to prevent anonymous access to WCF services that we can consider?
It seems to me that there should be a rather straight-forward solution for this somehow.
We're certainly not the first ones to want to secure our custom WCF services in claims-based SharePoint from anonymous access, that's for sure.

Could we be missing something trivial but crucial?

Thanks, Eddy